# Why do HEIC/HEIF files have a blank file type in a FileList?

Tags: javascript, filelist, heic, heif

I'm using the file select input to upload multiple files. After a user selects their files, I'm sorting through the `FileList` in a loop to check if there are any HEIC/HEIF files, so I can display an error message.

```js
const fileSelect = document.createElement("input");
fileSelect.setAttribute("type", "file");
fileSelect.setAttribute("multiple", "multiple");
fileSelect.click();
```

```js
if(!this.vm.acceptedTypes.includes(file.type)) {
  console.log(file);
  this._$inj.globalFac.showAlert(file.name, `Error: File type ${file.type} is not supported.`);
  continue;
}
```

However, when a user uploads a HEIC/HEIF file, the `type` property is blank. Why?

[image: File Object with blank type]

Comment: [`.type`](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#dfn-type): _"On getting, user agents must return the type of a Blob as an ASCII-encoded string in lower case, such that when it is converted to a byte sequence, **it is a [parsable MIME type](https://mimesniff.spec.whatwg.org/#parse-a-mime-type), or the empty string – 0 bytes – if the type cannot be determined**."_

Comment: So HEIC/HEIF files don't have a parsable MIME type?

Comment: I'm still wondering Why this is

Comment: It have the correct type in mac that is "image/heif", but in windows it is ''